# trim the string and return an array of phrases

Tags: javascript

I have a string consisting of pairs of phrases separated with `=` sign.

```
let trapSt = 'i was sent = i sent. to protect you = to find you. they are = we are.';
```

Note that each pair is separated from others with a dot.

Now I want to create an array using the above string like this (there is only one space between each word and between words and `=` sign):

```
["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you", "they are = we are"]
```

So I've written this (I have tried to return the above array no matter how you defined the strig ):

```js
let trapSt = '   i  was    sent =     i sent   .to protect    you= to find you. they are =we are.   ';

trapSt = trapSt.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(".").map(s => s.trim());
trapSt = trapSt.filter(s => s);

console.log(trapSt);
```

As you see this is not what we want: we want `to protect you = to find you` instead of `to protect you= to find you`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: split by period first, then trim each token

Comment: How?...........

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let trapSt = '   i  was    sent =     i sent   .to protect    you= to find you. they are =we are.   ';

trapSt = trapSt.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(".").map(s => s.trim());
trapSt = trapSt.map(s => s.split("=").map(s => s.trim()).join(" = "));  // split each element again by "=", trim it, and join it again
trapSt = trapSt.filter(s => s);

console.log(trapSt);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Spit by period
2. Trim each piece

   1. Replace the = with a = surrounded by spaces (which may introduce double spacing)
   2. Remove all repeated spacing
3. Filter out any results that are blank strings to handle for the ending period

```js
let trapSt = '   i  was    sent =     i sent   .to protect    you= to find you. they are =we are.   ';

console.log(
  trapSt.split('.')
    .map(it => it.trim().replace(/=/, ' = ').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ') )
    .filter(it => it)
);
```